# featherlight.js - Run script on modal load

Tags: javascript, ajax, featherlight.js

Problem
HTML

```
<div id="form-lightbox">
<div class="form">
    <div id="ajaxreplace">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery(function() { 
                jQuery.ajaxReplace({ 
                    //parameters
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#form-lightbox">open lightbox</a>
```

It is a custom script that replaces the script with a form from the backend.

The problem is, that featherlight.js copies the source and displays
the clone in the lightbox.
That duplication of code can't be handled by the library for the form.

I changed the script-tag-type to "text/x-template" so the script does
not run directly. But then the form isn't rendered in the lightbox.

Question: How can I use featherlight to run the script on loading the the lightbox?

Comment: So you're wanting to edit JS using JS before it runs on a page?

Comment: @evolutionxbox maybe it helps to replace the x-template with javascript on loading? But I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Am I correct in my summary of your aim?

Comment: I want to run the script on opening the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

To run code after the lightbox is opened, use callbacks (e.g. `afterOpen`).

If you don't want content to be duplicated, use the `persist` option.

HTH